# Django json data in request.body but empty

Tags: python, json, django, nginx, request

I'm using an API which requires to send a callback to a url. Thus I configure my url and my view :

```
def get_callback(request):
    ...
    some treatment with request.body
```

My view always returns that request.body contains " b'' ". However, it must contain a lot of informations, encoded in JSON.
Indeed I know that theses informations are well sent to the callback url, I tried with requestbin.in (http://requestb.in/1d4dkk01?inspect#10fl7s) and the raw body is full.

What could case the body to be empty ? Could it be the nginx configuration ? or in setting.py ?

Thanks you

Comment: Requestbin shows `Content-Type: multipart/form-data`, there is no json.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should return response have kind of json data for view. Like it

```
   import json
   def get_call_back(request):
          # Do something to return dictionary same as {'abc': xyz}
          json_data = json.dumps(data) 
          return HttpResponse(json_data, content_type='application/json')
```